# Count doesn't give back 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I must recover for each month the count of Groups that will be taking lessons, this check has to be done every three months, the final output should be this:

```
Gruppi A nel mese di Luglio    20
Gruppi A nel mese di Agosto    18
Gruppi A nel mese di Settembre  5
Gruppi B nel mese di Luglio     8
Gruppi B nel mese di Agosto     0
Gruppi B nel mese di Setembre  12
```

This is my query:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month') AS FORMAT_MONTH,
         COUNT(*) AS COUNT_GROUPS
  FROM REVIEW 
    INNER JOIN GROUPS ON REVIEW.ID = GROUPS.ID
  WHERE GROUP_TYPE = 1
   AND GROUP_MASTER = 50
   AND TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'YYYYMM') 
         IN ((SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 0), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL), 
             (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 1), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL), (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 2), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL))
  GROUP BY GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month')

  UNION ALL

  SELECT GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month') AS FORMAT_MONTH,
         COUNT(*) AS COUNT_GROUPS
  FROM REVIEW 
     INNER JOIN GROUPS ON REVIEW.ID = GROUPS.ID
  WHERE GROUP_TYPE = 1
    AND GROUP_MASTER = 50
    AND TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'YYYYMM') IN ((SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 0), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL), 
                                                  (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 1), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL), 
                                                  (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 2), 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL))
  GROUP BY GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month')
) 
SELECT * 
FROM T 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Gruppi nel periodo', SUM(COUNT_GROUPS) 
FROM T;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `select` for the `IN` values is not necessary. You can simplify that to: `IN ( TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'), 0), 'YYYYMM'), ...`). That expression can further be simplified to a simple: `where review.review_date between date '2016-07-01' and date add_months('2016-07-01', 2)`

Comment: Please post a reduced set of data with desired result. Here we know what you need, but not where you are starting from. Also, what is the problem with your query? Is it giving an error? a wrong result? [mcve] can be very useful

Comment: Instead of giving me 'Gruppi nel mese di Agosto 0' it doesn't show up that line since the where doesn't match the results

Comment: You probably simply need a left outer join instead of an inner join. Also, why the union all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may rewrite your query like that.

1. If you want see groups without REVIEW you should yse left join.
2. Why you get data twice with the equal param (I delete it from my query)
3. For total you may use group by rollup()
4. IMHO/ You may use trunc(date.'mm') for comparing date by months
5. **EDIT:** Move check review dates to join condition.

I assume **GROUP_TYPE** and **GROUP_MASTER** are belong to groups My code look like:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 
     GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(d.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month')  AS FORMAT_MONTH,
     COUNT(REVIEW.ID) AS COUNT_GROUPS
  FROM GROUPS 
       JOIN (SELECT add_months(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'),0) as REVIEW_DATE from DUAL UNION ALL 
             SELECT add_months(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'),1) from DUAL UNION ALL 
             SELECT add_months(TO_DATE('20160701', 'YYYYMMDD'),2) from DUAL ) d ON 1=1
       LEFT JOIN REVIEW ON REVIEW.ID = GROUPS.ID AND trunc(REVIEW.REVIEW_DATE, 'MM') = d.REVIEW_DATE
  WHERE GROUP_TYPE = 1
   AND GROUP_MASTER = 50
  GROUP BY rollup(GROUPS.GROUP_NAME || ' nel mese di ' || TO_CHAR(d.REVIEW_DATE, 'Month'))
  ) 
  SELECT  nvl(FORMAT_MONTH,'Gruppi nel periodo') as FORMAT_MONTH
          ,COUNT_GROUPS 
  FROM T ;
```

Comment: I think you have the NVL in the wrong place

Comment: `.. =  IN (..)` is wrong

Comment: Thank you. Another I add some another remarks.